# How would you do heavy processing in Meteor?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I have a meteor app that is currently pulling data from twitter and is subsequently doing some manipulation and then inserting the documents into a collection. Let's say I run this process forever but don't want to block the event loop, is there any solution for this?

Note: I know node.js is single-threaded, and meteor doesn't support packages such as cluster because it requires sticky sessions. The only solution I can think of is adding a server dedicated to processing the data coming in from twitter and forwarding the requests to that server but then I have no longer have a case to use Meteor or node.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using another server or process on the same server seems like a logical solution. Could the meteor process and the worker process just communicate through the database itself? e.g. the worker process just writes to some results collection which is then used on the client? It's hard to suggest more without knowing the exact nature of the problem.

Comment: Why would your data archival script need to be within Meteor? You could create a collection within Meteor, and then insert data into the MongoDB collection directly from Node. That way you could use Cluster, and you wouldn't block the event loop. You could even have the data collection scripts running on another server. As mentioned above it's hard to suggest more without understanding the nature of what you're building.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://meteorhacks.com/fibers-eventloop-and-meteor.html)?  Providing a simple example of what you want would be helpful.  You can probably do what you want within meteor using node event emitters and fibers.

Answer (score 1):

The truth here is that while javascript/node/meteor might be capable to do processing in, you yourself really don't want to do that. Let me give some observations and a personal example:

- Your app is all about the latency. If one of your requests takes long to complete because it is stuck in a tight loop it affects every other client connected to your server at that moment. Everybody's latency will increase if this happens. (This is the case for making sure you have no tight loops in your code)
- Javascript (the language) has very unsophisticated support for numeric values. (You basically get a `double`). Things like `float`, `long`, `int`, `byte` are all meant to allow you to do tight loops as fast as possible. If you can represent a value in a primitive type most closely matched to it you will get a lot of improvement. (This is the case for extracting your data processing to a language suited for data processing)

I was prototyping an app that had to do some aggregations over data. I fired it in meteor using a `setInterval` callback and it took about 2 seconds to complete each time. On my own development machine I didn't really notice it (because meteor apps hide latency issues very effectively). As soon as I deployed it and started looking at the logs I realized that not a single user had latency on any request below 4 seconds. This is horrible client experience.

I extracted the number crunching to a small `clojure` app. All integration happens via records inserted and read from the mongo db and the clojure code has some timed events firing every couple of seconds doing exactly the same calcs as was previously done in meteor.

In clojure those calcs now take less than 100ms in total (compared to 2-4 seconds in meteor).

To come back to your question: It doesn't sound like your application has a user interface? If it does, you would do well to keep that in meteor because it's excellent for web UI's. But it's not the right technology for headless apps, which it sounds to me like you have.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.unblock() within the beginning of your method that does the heavy processing. Meteor will than start another fiber, go on with processing your method, fire the callback when it is done. More info here: http://docs.meteor.com/#method_unblock